# WP Query, with ACF to NOT show posts with a date older than today

Tags: php, wordpress

Morning all,

I'm attempting to loop through posts in a specific category if the custom field (event_date) (ACF) is older than today. The query I'm using is:

```
$today = current_time('Ymd');
$args = array(
'category' => 42, // Events category
'post_status' => 'publish', // Published
'posts_per_page' => '0', // Unlimited posts per page
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'event_date', // Only loop through posts when the event date
        'compare' => '>', // Is greater than $today, ie in the future
        'value' => $today, 
    )
),
'meta_key' => 'event_date',
'orderby' => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC',
);
```

In ACF, I've set the saved date to be default (yymmdd) and I've set it to match the $today var (Ymd) yet it's still showing an event from 23rd June.

The client wanted them listed to show the events in date order, but to not show past events. I've got it half working, however this one is causing me some issues as I believe it should be working. I've double checked everything in the backend and all looks good. I may be having a blonde moment too...

Any assistance would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), and it looks like WP might have an issue with ordering by meta_value that consists of numbers. Copied below:

> 'meta_value' - Note that a 'meta_key=keyname' must also be present in
>   the query. Note also that the sorting will be alphabetical which is
>   fine for strings (i.e. words), but can be unexpected for numbers (e.g.
>   1, 3, 34, 4, 56, 6, etc, rather than 1, 3, 4, 6, 34, 56 as you might
>   naturally expect). Use 'meta_value_num' instead for numeric values.
>   You may also specify 'meta_type' if you want to cast the meta value as
>   a specific type. Possible values are 'NUMERIC', 'BINARY', 'CHAR',
>   'DATE', 'DATETIME', 'DECIMAL', 'SIGNED', 'TIME', 'UNSIGNED', same as
>   in '$meta_query'. When using 'meta_type' you can also use meta_value_*
>   accordingly. For example, when using DATETIME as 'meta_type' you can
>   use 'meta_value_datetime' to define order structure.

So I'd try `meta_value_num` first to see if it works. 
If not, I'd cast the meta_type as `DATE` or `DATETIME`.

---

**Notes:**

- `'posts_per_page' => -1,` to show all posts not `'posts_per_page' => '0',`
- `'cat' => 42,` not `'category' => 42,`

Comment: Thanks mate, completely missed those last points! It's kinda working.. The July 23rd event is still showing, but at the very bottom of the list, so the ordering is working now after changing 'meta_value' to 'meta_value_num' (without a 'meta_type'). Odd this one... Link is https://touchstonecrm.co.uk/events/ if you want to take a look to see what I mean

Comment: If `current_time` is returning a string it should be fine. Do you think the same issue of `meta_value_num` happening with `compare`? Because the issue might be comparing as strings is not the same as numerical. There's a `type` parameter in `meta_query`. Could you try setting it to different values?

Comment: Try something like `'type' => 'NUMERIC',`